# Objective-C: Compiler Errors Passing Self to Method in a Selector

Tags: objective-c, ios

So, I'm trying to call a method in another object and pass the calling object as part of the call. Could be the way I'm architecting it just makes no sense, but anyway here's the call:

```
NSTimer *refreshTimer = [NSTimer
                         scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:[timerDate timeIntervalSinceNow]
                         target:otherObject
                         selector:@selector(methodBeingCalled:self)
                         userInfo:nil
                         repeats:NO];
```

And the receiving method has the following signature:

```
- (void)methodBeingCalled:(id)sender;
```

When I do this, I get an error on the call that says, "Error expected ':'". Which doesn't make sense to me, because I've got a colon in there to pass "self" as a parameter.

Am I using the selector incorrectly? Should I be using an NSInvocation instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't get to set the parameters like that.  A selector only defines the signature and how many arguments a function has.  Remove `self`, because you can't send it.  If you want to pass `self`, do it in `userInfo`.  The object that will come in an `NSTimer` method is the `NSTimer` itself.

P.S. [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html) is your friend.  It clearly states there (for the selector argument) that "The selector must correspond to a method that returns void and takes a single argument. The timer passes itself as the argument to this method."

Comment: That's awesome, thanks for the tip.

So, if I understand correctly, just doing @selector(methodBeingCalled:) would send the Timer object itself to methodBeingCalled?